# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I got this error when i try to see the content.

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Controller

```
$form->school_id = $request->get(SchoolsList::id);
```

blade.php

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $school->id }}" name="school_id">
```

The connection with the database is not giving errors.

Comment: I am trying it but any own do not answer.

Comment: This is not a reason to post a duplicate.

Comment: @Daniel Execuse me. other will not be repeated answer my question